# Navigation Bar in Html file

Tags: html, navigation

I have created a website. Where i have written code for a very navigation bar code. All the pages need to have same navigation bar. Can any tell me how to do it without re-writing it. Can we refer same code from another file.

Code which i have written

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Home</strong></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="clients.html">Our Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP aswel,

Save your navigation html as nav.html

Then you can include it using PHP:

```
<?php
include ('nav.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible. HTML5 is a static language. However, you can create a Javascript to add the code you've written to your html code.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML it's not possible to include some other file. However you could use shtml/server side includes.

Comment: I have n 8 pages in my website, there i want to have common top tab (navigation bar). The content of this should not change only the buttom form should be loaded when clicked.. Is it possible to do this ? If yes how to do.. Plz help me...